# Bash script declare

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a simple bash script that will ask a user for input and then echo the value in the declares based on the number they choose.

```
declare -A bla
bla[1]="bla1"
bla[2]="bla2"

echo "What bla would you like?"
echo ""
echo "1) bla1"
echo "2) bla2"

read answer
echo "bla[$answer]"
```

When I run this script I am expecting the output to be either "bla1" or "bla2" depending if they typed 1 or 2. Although I only get the ouput: "bla[1]" or "bla[2]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `bla[$answer]` is a string with a variable expansion inside it (`$answer`). You need an array expansion. (e.g. `${bla[$answer]}`).

Comment: I just tried that and the output I get is "./bla.sh: Bad substitution"

Comment: What shell are you using? Is it really bash? Did you type exactly what I wrote? Can you add `set -vx` to the top of the script and show the output?

Comment: #!/bin/sh
declare -A bla
++ declare -A bla
bla[1]="bla1"
++ bla[1]=bla1
bla[2]="bla2"
++ bla[2]=bla2

echo "What bla would you like?"
++ echo 'What bla would you like?'
What bla would you like?
echo ""
++ echo ''

echo "1) bla1"
++ echo '1) bla1'
1) bla1
echo "2) bla2"
++ echo '2) bla2'
2) bla2

read answer
++ read answer
^[:q!
echo "${bla[$answer]}"
++ echo ''

Answer (score 2):

You want to use bash's `select` command here:

```
bla=( bla1 bla2 )
PS3="What bla would you like? "
select b in "${bla[@]}"; do
    [[ $b ]] && break
done
echo "you want: $b"
```

Notes:

- a regular array suffices, you don't need an associative array if you're just using integer indices.
- the array expansion `"${bla[@]}"` is required to expand the array into its constituent elements.
- when the user enters a valid response, the `$b` variable will be non-null, and the `break` statement exits the `select` "loop".

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out I was using

`#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash` and needed to edit `${bla[$answer]}`

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I'd have expected `/bin/sh` to choke on `declare -A` well before the new substituion but ok.